# Selenium WebDriver can't find element radiobutton by Text

Tags: c#, selenium

view the html on the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBepl.png

Hello , I need to get a radio button with a specific text however the text is not within the input but after him.

Follow the image below shows where the text is .

How could select the first or second radio button the text in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to locate the text node and then get the [preceding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) `input` element, e.g.:

```
//text()[contains(., "Abranches")]/preceding::input[@id = "enderecoDes"]
```